# How can I get my Android app with use Branch.io Deeplinking AND support minimize/resume the app?

Tags: java, android, branch.io

I am using **Branch.io** deeplinking in my Android app, and for the most part, it works well under most scenarios. However, I have a scenario where I register a user (to my service); and in that flow, the user requests an SMS verification code, and thus has to leave the app (minimize) to read it, then re-enter the app (restore) to validate to code.

I had this behavior working perfectly *before* implementing branch.io, and the reason has to do with Branch.io requiring `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file (see [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking)).

```
<activity
   android:name="com.yourapp.SplashActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   ...
```

When `android:launchMode="singleTask"` is removed, the user can leave/enter the app as much as they want and are always returned to the same activity that they were on when they minimized the app. Yet, Branch.io deeplinking is no longer respected.

*HOWEVER*, it seems that this minimize/restore behaivor is **not** (?) possible with Branch.io is implemented. Is it? **How can I retain the minimize/restore functionality of my app, which implementing Branch.io deeplinking?**

Comment: So when you have Branch integrated, what is the behavior when you minimize the App? Does the same Activity not open?

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh When Branch.io is integrated correctly (ie, when `android:launchMode="singleTask"` is included in the manifest), the app **always** opens on the splash screen.

Comment: by minimize you mean just pressing the home button right and not completely closing the App. correct? I have a Sample App available on my Github Account

Comment: That is correct.  Oh yeah? I see branch_web on your github. That looks related to web though. Whats the repo called?

Comment: By minimize you mean just pressing the home button right and not completely closing the App. correct?  Minimising the App should not cause your App to restart. I have a Sample App available on my Github Account [here](https://github.com/amruta-d/Sample-Android-App/tree/master/MyApplication). In this App, when you minimize the App and reopen it does not restart the App.

Comment: I appreciate you posting that. However, that example actually contains the same issue that I am referring to in the post. For example, if you go to `RedActivity`, then minimize (via Home button), then resume (via app icon), then you are left back on the `MainActivity` view. If you remove `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, then the app will resume on `RedActivity` where the user was when they minimized. However, the Branch functionality is dead.

Comment: Ah, I see, when I resume via the app icon, it starts from a "closed" state. When I resume via "app expose", then it opens at the correct activity. Interesting...

Comment: unfortunately, that is default Android behavior. I.e. clicking on App icon will restart the Launcher Activity. Also, we require the ACtivity used for Deeplinking have the launch mode set to `SingleTask` to avoid creating multiple instances of the Activity in the Activity Stack. If you reset the Launch mode to default, it would open multiple instances of the same Activity and cause issues with deep linking.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help. If you wrap that up in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Amruta's comment I wanted to contribute. As singleTask is required for proper deep linking to avoid multiple instances of the same activity, our best workaround/suggestion for this issue which hasn't been mentioned yet is to create a [transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android) deep linking activity. This way you can set a throw away transparent activity to singleTask, init session from it it -> grab params -> route accordingly. Otherwise you're stuck adjusting your main app flow to our requirement of using singleTask. This tends to be the most popular workaround!